# Is there a directive or other way to instruct VS to use a certain framework or language version in intellisense?

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction, visual-studio-2013, directive

I occasionally need to edit .vb files in Visual Studio that are not associated with a project or solution file.  VS seems to assume a fairly old version of the language and .net framework.

Is there any compiler directive or other setting I could use in Visual Studio to force it to treat the file as a newer version of VB and .net framework?

Comment: what new .net framework features is it missing?

Comment: @CoderDennis: e.g. `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`

Answer (score 2):

VB.NET projects get quite a few references and imported namespaces by default. It's probably not that Visual Studio is assuming an old version of the language, but just that references to `System.Collections`, `System.Collections.Generic`, `System.Linq`, etc. are not seen when the .vb file is opened outside of a project that includes those default imported namespaces.

The same behavior exists in a C# file that is opened outside of its project. You don't get Intellisense on features of libraries that do not have a project reference that Visual Studio can see. I'm not sure what you would do to work around that other than just creating an empty project and adding the file in question to that project.

The .net framework version is also a project setting, so that may also be part of your issue. If there is a solution for giving Visual Studio those settings without a project file, then someone with more experience than I have would need to chime in.

**Edit:** `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` is defined in the `System` namespace, so Visual Studio requires a project reference to the `System.dll` assembly and a namespace import in order to see it.

It looks like the only thing Visual Studio gives you for a file that's outside a project is the syntax highlighting. I don't get any Intellisense at all when editing a .vb file on its own even for classes defined within the file itself.